# Unity 2d Box Collider 2d лестница - проверить, что подъем завершен

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Добавил возможность подъема по лестнице в 2d платформере с помощью OnTriggerStay2D() и OnTriggerExit2D(). 
Но как проверить, что игрок при достижении верхушки лестницы стоит над компонентом Box Collider 2D лестницы?

Answer (score 2):

Уф, тебе нужно create Empty на лестнице, участок на котором он должен стать(вверху), затем пишешь код снизу, надеюсь нормально объяснил в коментах

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Сюда засовываешь свою шутку которую ты создал и разместил на верхнем boxcolider 2d;
    public Transform topCheck;
    //Проверяет находится ли игрок наверху, если да - возвращает true
     bool onTop;
    //Сюда нужно внести Layer, на которого она будет реагировать, например дай своему персонажу layer Player
    public LayerMask whatisground;
    //Сюда расстояние на которое оно проверяет игрока
    public float checkRadius;


void Update()

{
    //Здесь риссуется круг, который чекает твоего игрока в радиусе котором ты указал
    onTop = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(topCheck.position, checkRadius, whatisground);

    //Если оно находит игрока, то в консоль пишется  "Tu naverhu"
    if (onTop)
    {
       print("Tu naverhu");
    }


}
```

}